# Powershell Get-ADUser - invalid enumeration context error

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm having issues getting all AD users in my work environment.
It runs for about 30 minutes before displaying the following error below:

```
    Get-ADUser : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.
At line:3 char:19
+                   Get-ADUser  -filter * -Properties * |
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

I did some research and found out that MaxEnumContextExpiration = 30 Mins and figured that's the reason why it stops running at 30 Minutes.

My question is: Is there a quicker way to pull all the users in my work environment(about 60k employees)along with all their info(Name, Samaccountname,Description, Group Membership,Account Status, etc...)

This is the script I currently have:

```
              Import-module activedirectory
              $daTA=@(
              Get-ADUser  -filter * -Properties * |  
              Select-Object @{Label = "FirstName";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},  
              @{Name = "LastName";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
              @{Name = "Full address";Expression = {$_.StreetAddress}},
              @{Name = "Fullname";Expression = {$_.Name}},
              @{Name = "LogonName";Expression = {$_.Samaccountname}},
              @{Name = "City";Expression = {$_.City}}, 
              @{Name = "State";Expression = {$_.st}}, 
              @{Name = "Post Code";Expression = {$_.PostalCode}}, 
              @{Name = "Country/Region";Expression ={$_.Country}},
              @{Name = "MobileNumber";Expression = {$_.mobile}},
              @{Name = "Phone";Expression = {$_.telephoneNumber}}, 
              @{Name = "Description";Expression = {$_.Description}},
              @{name=  "OU";expression={$_.DistinguishedName.split(',')[1].split('=')[1]}},
              @{Name = "Email";Expression = {$_.Mail}},
              @{Name = "MemberOfGroups";e= { ( $_.memberof | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name }) -join “,” }},
              @{Name = "Primary Group";Expression= {$_.primarygroup  -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}},
              @{Name = "UserPrincipalName";Expression = {$_.UserPrincipalName}},
              @{Name = "LastLogonTimeSTamp";Expression = {if(($_.lastLogonTimestamp -like '*1/1/1601*' -or $_.lastLogonTimestamp -eq $null)){'NeverLoggedIn'} Else{[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}},
              @{Name = "Account Status";Expression = {if (($_.Enabled -eq 'TRUE')  ) {'Enabled'} Else {'Disabled'}}},
              @{Name = "LastLogonDate";Expression = {if(($_.lastlogondate -like '*1/1/1601*' -or $_.lastlogondate -eq $null)){'NeverLoggedIn'} Else{$_.lastlogondate}}},
              @{Name = "WhenUserWasCreated";Expression = {$_.whenCreated}},
              @{Name = "accountexpiratondate";Expression = {$_.accountexpiratondate}},
              @{Name = "PasswordLastSet";Expression = {([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet))}},
              @{Name = "PasswordExpiryDate";Expression={([datetime]::fromfiletime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")).DateTime}},
              @{Name = "Password Never";Expression = {$_.passwordneverexpires}},
              @{Name = "HomeDriveLetter";Expression = {$_.HomeDrive}},
              @{Name = "HomeFolder";Expression = {$_.HomeDirectory}},
              @{Name = "scriptpath";Expression = {$_.scriptpath}},
              @{Name = "HomePage";Expression = {$_.HomePage}},
              @{Name = "Department";Expression = {$_.Department}},
              @{Name = "EmployeeID";Expression = {$_.EmployeeID}},
              @{Name = "Job Title";Expression = {$_.Title}},
              @{Name = "EmployeeNumber";Expression = {$_.EmployeeNumber}},
              @{Name = "Manager";Expression={($_.manager -replace 'CN=(.+?),(OU|DC)=.+','$1')}}, 
              @{Name = "Company";Expression = {$_.Company}},
              @{Name = "Office";Expression = {$_.OfficeName}}
              )
              $DAta | Sort LastLogondate -Descending | 
              Export-Csv -Path c:\adusers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I have 16,000 AD users apparently and takes me about 4 minutes 30 seconds using `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *` and 5 minutes 5 seconds if I add `| Select *`. I think defining all those labels may be slowing it down a bit.

Comment: can you grab the objects by OU instead of "the entire blithering AD"? [*grin*] ///// also, you may want to grab them 1st into a $Var and then iterate thru the collection. dunno how much RAM that will take, tho. ///// also also, try lightening the load on your AD server by only getting the properties you NEED. getting them all is supposed to be a really heavy load ...

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this issue myself, but mainly because I don't have a big enough AD environment to test on!

On an assumption, I figured there may have been a `-ResultSize` switch, this is what I found:

> -ResultSetSize
>   Specifies the maximum number of objects to return for an Active Directory Domain Services query. If you want to receive all of the objects, set this parameter to $null (null value). You can use Ctrl+c to stop the query and return of objects.
>
> The default is $null.
>
> The following example shows how to set this parameter so that you receive all of the returned objects.
>
> -ResultSetSize $null

[Source for above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserver2012r2-ps)

I know it says the default is already set to `$null`, but may be worth trying to include the switch and see if it makes a difference.

It would definitely be good to follow the advice already suggested by @Drew and @Lee_Dailey.

Filtering by OU will make a big dent in the speed and resource cost on the server side for the request, and requesting only the properties you need will help speed it up as well as reduce the load / RAM needed (if you're storing it all in a variable).

Let me know if this does help, as I'm curious myself!